# How to manipulate with embedded SVG data?

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I am coding application with SVG and pure JavaScript. I have situation where one of my SVG document fragments is  loaded from outer *.svg file and xlinked as `<image>`. However, I can't call objects (SVG Elements) from this file to manipulate with them. Does DOM support that, am I doing something wrong... it looks trivial, but I can't handle with that.

Something like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <svg>
    <someTags
    />
  </svg>
    <g>
      <image id="outerSVG" xlink:href="files/SVGelements.svg" />
    </g>

</svg>
```

Those problem is drive me crazy, especially  for now I need to load saved fragments of SVG and parse it to main SVG, scripted file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<image>` element in svg is essentially the same as the `<img>` element in html, neither of them allow DOM access to the referenced resource.

Comment: Thanks @Erik, I wish I knew that before. Please can you tell me what is the "easiest" way to load and insert SVG data from outer file...PHP...Django...and to allow main SVG scripted app to manipulate with SVGElements?

Comment: There's probably more than one way to do this, but I would suggest XmlHttpRequest and inserting the elements directly into the main document.

Comment: Thank you. Now I know where to start.